# Java authentication and password changing periodically

Tags: java, authentication, passwords

I have a java application and there are only two users that can utilize this application, and the difference between them is that one can use a printing menu from a menubar and the other one cannot do his.

So to do this, i made this 'log in' frame which contains obviously the user name field and the password, and three buttons, "Connect" "Cancel" And the third one is "Change password".

The problem of course lies in the last one.. The application should actually change the "password" periodically, saying for example every 3 months the user is notified, and can do it through a Jdialog with three text fields(old password, new one and confirm password) just by clicking on the "Change password" button.

Well here's the 'probably stupid' question: how can i make the application store the password and username, notify the user, and allow him to change the password, all this without having a database? Since the database is ready to use, and i didn't make it and i don't have access to add anything to it...

By the way the application is a desktop app and i searched for authentication plugins and whatnot, but i only found server app authentications, and i don't think they're the same concept, but who am i to say that, i'm only novice in java.

Hope i clarified the question enough. and thank you in advance.

Comment: It would reeeeaaaaly be better if you could store your data in your database. However, if you can't, you can have a look at serialization. It allows you to export Java objects (for instance, your Users) to a file. That way, you load you serialized file everytime you start your app, and export the updated data to your file everytime you close it.

Comment: Why? IMO regular password resets are a waste of time and a major annoyance to users. There isn't actually a concrete reason to change a password that hasn't been comprised.

Comment: @EJP That's a waist of time and a major annoyance to me more than to the user lol! but it's actually not a choice, the "un-paying client" needs that, to make more sense, the user changes his password to login to his user account on windows periodically, for security issues (this application is for an enterprise by the way), and this user in question wants to change the password of the app simultaneously with the changing of the user account password (which are the same by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) is the process of exporting an Object structure & value to a file. This allows you to save the state of your data, and easily reload it at each launch of your app.

While you could just store the value of each field of your objects in a text file, this can be rather complicated if your Objects are complex. Serialization however is automated and quite simple to implement (as often in Java) and you can find plenty of examples [like this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) about how to use it on the internet.

Comment: That looks rather good, i will try it and tell give feedback. Though, a part of the question remains unanswered, how can i use the serialization concept to notify the user at the right time, should i test the "last modified" field of the file (which seems to be kind of complex to do) or what exactly. And in the example you gave me (which is a really good one) they advice to save the file as an .ser file, do you think i should do that or save it to another extension? 
Thank you for your answers :).

Comment: @user3610008 You could add a date field to your User object. When you modify your password, update this field. Whenever you launch your app, you can check the date and notify the users which password needs updating. To address the 2nd part of your comment, java doesn't care about the extension. The `.ser` is standard though. It is to be noted that the file can be located anywhere, not necessarily on the local computer. Taht way, you can keep your `.ser` file on server so that modifications are synchronized between users. It however requires some configuration to do so

Comment: Thank you for you help, it worked for me! 
I also made "Change password by choice" aspect, and it worked too, thank you a lot.
Now i'll try the Date field.
And for the .ser file, i actually created it in the resources of my application, and it'll be contained in the jar file, that i would deploy on the server as a last step of my application. I think that would work. (I never made an application on a server, but to follow the logic, or my logic at least, i think it'll work)

Comment: @user3610008 Sure, if your app is deployed on a server, you won't have any issue with data synchonization. Be carefull with simultaneous access though. Good luck with the rest ;)

Comment: @user3610008 As a side note, to avoid issues about simultaneous access, you could store each user in a different `.ser` file. You could name the files `username1.ser`, `username2.ser`, ... and when you load your data, load every `.ser` files.

Comment: That's exactly what i did actually! a lot of tests.. but at least we are sure we don't have a problem about simultaneous access as you said.

Answer (score -1):

Well, one way to do it, although it's not safe, is to add few variables in the program, like : userName1, userName2, password1, password2, where you will store the user names and passwords, they will be static variables and you will have to hard code them. Then, add 2 more variables of type Date, where you will store the last date when the password has been changed, and then, apply your logic. Obviously, this is not the best solution, it is not scalable, it will be very hard to maintain it if you have to add more users. But, if you can't use a database (which I strongly recommend you do), then I guess this is one way to go.

Comment: This won't work. Passwords will be reset to their default value everytime you restart your app. It only works if the app runs 24/7

Comment: Well, here I assume that the programmer knows the usernames and the passwords, so he can add them in the program as static variables (ex : password1="dfsfvsvs"). I already said this is hardly a way to do it, but if he can't use a database, this is one of the solutions I thought of, I would like to hear of better solutions, this question intrigued me.

Comment: I will elaborate my comment about serialization then. THe issue about your answer is that while you can keep the updated passwords at runtine, as passwords are hard-coded with a default value, you will rollback to the default value at every restart of the app, yet OP would like to keep the updated password around

Comment: Post it as an answer, I would like to see this solution. Also, now that I've given it some thought, he could write the passwords in txt files, the file can serve him as a "database".

Comment: @user3722371 that's exactly what i thought about at first, but then i thought like ploutox, i need something to be constant, plus it won't be me that will use this application, the users don't know IT...

Comment: @Ploutox i'll wait for your answer, thank you. And yeah about the text file, i thought about that, but the problem is that i still don't know how to extract strings from a .txt file.